# how to pass data from dialog to parent component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material

I have a dialog as shown below, my goal with this project is to pass data about the selected agreement when Open button is clicked to the document viewer component letting the viewer access the document however i am having trouble passing the data from my .ts file for the dialog through to the other component.

This list is populated from my firestore database and gets all documents the user has created successfully.
[image]

Code from dialog i am trying to pass to the nav:

```
openDocument(docID: any, address: any, advanceFee:any, artistName:any, commenceDate:any, commision:any, currency:any, distro:any,mixOption:any, ownerEmail: any, postal:any, prod:any, prodDate:any,prodFee:any,prodRoyalties:any,producerName:any,receiverSigned:any,receivingParty:any, selectedServices:any,senderSigned:any,sendingParty:any,services:any,syncCommision:any,termMonths:any,territories:any,territoryType:any,trackList:any){
console.log(docID)
this.myAgreements.forEach((doc: { docID: any; }) => {
  if(doc.docID == docID){
    this.data.docID = docID;
  }
});
this.dialogRef.close();
```

I have noticed you cant set the data in typescript using the line this.data.docID = docID, so im trying to figure out the best way to give the data back to the other component.

My idea was to user this.data.docID = docID.

then in the dialog close section use this.docID = result.docID, however this did not work as i wanted.

This is the values in the other component i am wanting to set from the chosen document:

```
receivingParty: string = "";
sendingParty: string = "";
address: string = "";
phoneNumber: string = "";
postal: number = 0;
commenceDate: string = "";
termMonths: number = 0;
territoryType: string = "";
territories: string = "";
commision: number = 0;
syncCommision: number = 0;
syncPlacementsOption: boolean = false;
selectedServices: string[] = [];
servicesEnabled: boolean = false;
distro: boolean = false;
prod: boolean = false;
//prod
artistName: string = "";
producerName: string = "";
prodDate: string = "";
mixOption: boolean = false;
prodFee: number = 0;
currency: string = "NZD";
advanceFee: number = 0;
prodRoyalties: number = 0;
newTrackName: string = "";
newRoyalty: string = "";
trackList: prodTrackData[] = [];
newFullName: string = "";
```

Comment: Can you please share some working example. I may help on this. Thanks!

Comment: if i had a working example i probably wouldn’t need to ask how to do this lol

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you list documents as list items, you can do it easily like this:

In HTML:

```
<ul>

  <li *ngFor="let doc of documents" (click)="onClickDocument(doc)">{{doc}}</li>

</ul>
```

To send the data to parent component when a document is clicked in dialog.component.ts :

```
onClickDocument(doc) {
    this.dialogRef.close(doc);
}
```

To receive data from dialog in parent.component.ts:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YourDialogComponent)

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result) {
    //handle the data here
  }    
});
```